# Eclipse JPA- Hibernate is missing from the "Platform" list of JPA project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-tools

I'm trying to follow this Redhat tutorial, "Develop Applications Using the Hibernate Tools" in Eclipse.https://access.redhat.com/articles/2372001

All is well until the point where it says :
*In the Platform list, click Hibernate (JPA 2.1).*

There's only Generic there,although I have installed **Hibernate Tools**.

What am I missing,and is there any difference between Gerneric and Hibernate?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

To simulate this, I installed Hibernate Tools from JBoss Tools in marketplace and restarted ide then went to the menu mentioned there. I choose JPA version 2.1. When i click the Platform combo, it was there.

It must be something about your **Hibernate Tools** installation or inaccurate JPA version. Also generic and hibernate are different.

Comment: Hi which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Hi, It's 2021-3

Comment: Is it EE? for example I'm on "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers"

Comment: It was "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".